# tensorflow tape gradient return None

Tags: tensorflow, gradient

I want to debug this error , in this example, one should get 1
as output,  but I got None..
is this a tensorflow bug or there is another cause ?
the two arryas are identical .. when I replace y by x I got the expected output
`import tensorflow as tf

```
y = tf.cast([0.1,
               0.2,
               0.3,
               0.4], dtype=tf.float64)

x = tf.cast([0.1,
             0.2,
             0.3,
             0.4], dtype=tf.float64)

x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, 1))
y = tf.reshape(y, (-1, 1))
print(x.shape,phi.shape)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
   tape.watch(x)
   grad_y_x = tape.gradient(y,x)
   print(grad_y_x)
del tape`
```

how to avoid the None error ?
is tf . gradient() deprecated and can cause bugs ?
I tried tf . batch_jacobian but also gives a zero tensor
I also played with the tape . persist options but the issues persists

Answer (score 1):

For a gradient to get on the tape, there has to be operations in the forward function (i.e. in the `with GradientTape` context). There are no operations with x and y (or no operations at all), so no gradient is recorded and the tape returns None.